# is theren an alternative way to code / combine these? JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, refactoring

As seen below, one function shows two things and the other function hides those two things.
Somehow they are so similar that I really want to see if there's a way I can combine them together but I just couldn't think of a way to do it.

```
var btns = {
    filterBtn: function () {
        $('.filter-btn').on('click', function () {
            $('.cover').show();
            $('.popup').show();
        })
    },
    popupClose: function () {
        $('.popup-x-btn').on('click', function () {
            $('.cover').hide();
            $('.popup').hide();
        })
    }
}
```

Anyone has any suggestions?
Or it's the best to just leave it as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best refactoring I can think of would be to use [jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display), which you can use `true` to show the element or `false` to hide it:

```js
$('.showImage, .hideImage').on('click', function() {
  $('img').toggle($(this).hasClass('showImage'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="showImage">Show</button>
<button class="hideImage">Hide</button>
<br>
<img src="https://placeimg.com/250/250/any">
```

Or in your situation:

```
$('.filter-btn, .popup-x-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.cover, .popup').toggle($(this).hasClass('filter-btn'));
});
```

Comment: Didn't realise can put boolean into toggle to make things show or hide.  Thanks a lot for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its JS, you have so many possibilities:

```
function toggle(selector, dir) {
    return function() {
        $(selector).on('click', function() {
            $('.cover')[dir]();
            $('.popup')[dir]();
        });
    };
}

var btns = {
    filterBtn: toggle('.filter-btn', 'show'),
    popupClose: toggle('.popup-x-btn', 'hide'),
}
```

But is this **better**? Well, thats a personal opinion.

The important thing about JS is that you have so many ways to do everything, that the difficult thing is to find a consistent way to do things. Thats why people use more complex frameworks like react, angular, ember, vue, and so many more.

Comment: Sorry I gave the check to Daerik, your answer is lovely and did thought of doing it like this but didn't try yet.  Thinking if possible ways to shorten up codes like Daerik's sample but I love your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of jQuery's [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method.

```js
function toggleCoverAndPopup(showOrHide) {
  $('.cover, .popup').toggle(showOrHide);
}

var btns = {
  filterBtn: function() {
    $('.filter-btn').on('click', function() {
      toggleCoverAndPopup(true);
    })
  },
  popupClose: function() {
    $('.popup-x-btn').on('click', function() {
      toggleCoverAndPopup(false);
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with a simple if else statement.

```
$('.filter-btn .popup-x-btn').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("filter-btn")) {
    $('.cover').show();
    $('.popup').show();
  } else {
    $('.cover').hide();
    $('.popup').hide();
  }
});
```